# Select Mesmo Campo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

Olá!
Preciso fazer um SQL que me retorne o resultado e desejo na mesma linha. Hoje o SQL está pulando uma linha.
Preciso que fique na mesma linha.

```
select c.empresa, p.nome, (select count(sequencialOC) where OrdemAut = 'N') as 'Com cotação', (select count(sequencialOC) where OrdemAut = 'S') as 'Sem cotação' from compras c inner join pessoas p on (c.empresa = p.codigo) where c.data between '01/01/2020' and '29/09/2020' group by c.OrdemAut,c.Empresa, c.nome
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente explicar que resultado deseja obter e também com estes subselects que considero meio sem sentido.

Comment: A ideia é saber quais são as ORDEM de COMPRA de uma empresa que possuem cotação e quais ordem de compra não possuem cotação. 

Só desejo totalizar a quantidade de cada situação, filtrando por empresa e por data.

Answer (score 2):

Se consegui entender o que deseja talvez:

```
select c.empresa, p.nome, SUM(CASE WHEN OrdemAut = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Com cotação', SUM(CASE WHEN OrdemAut = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Sem cotação' 
from compras c inner join pessoas p on (c.empresa = p.codigo) 
where c.data between '01/01/2020' and '29/09/2020' 
group by c.Empresa, c.nome
```

possa atende-lo.

Comment: Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '='.

Entendi seu raciocínio e talvez dê certo, contudo, deu essa mensagem.

Comment: Faltou o WHEN. Corrigido.

Comment: Deu certo demaissssssss
Muito obrigado pela ajuda